# Classification of Lie group structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Is it possible to describe, up to isomorphism, all Lie groups $G$ whose underlying manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with its standard smooth structure)?

In fact, I haven't found any such group yet, other than the standard $(\mathbb{R}^n, +)$.

Comment: Off the top of my head: connected and simply connected nilpotent Lie groups are diffeomorphic to their Lie algebras (with the exponential mapping giving an explicit diffeomorphism).

Comment: Secondly: my impression - but as a spectator not a specialist - is that trying to classify all nilpotent Lie algebras over ${\bf R}$ runs into combinatorial explosion as the dimension of the algebra grows.

Comment: I didn't know this fact, thanks a lot! In principle, it exhausts my question since nilpotent Lie algebras are (up to isomorphism) subalgebras of $\mathfrak{n}(n, \mathbb{R})$, of which there are quite a few. But maybe someone else will give some clear examples of such groups directly.

Comment: More generally, any simply-connected solvable Lie group is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. 

If you restrict yourself to semisimple Lie groups then the only ones that occur are direct products of the universal cover of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: There are only two two-dimensional Lie algebras: abelian and non-abelian $[x, y] = x$. Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the only simply connected parallelizable 2-manifold, there must be two different Lie group structures on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Indeed, the second one is the group of orientation-preserving affine transformations $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For easy explicit nonabelian examples, take in dimension $n\ge 3$ the group of upper triangular matrices with diagonal 1, with entries playing the role of coordinates. In these cases the group law is polynomial in the coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YCor claims [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475385/under-what-conditions-is-the-exponential-map-on-a-lie-algebra-injective/1592257#1592257) that the contractible Lie groups (this is equivalent to being diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, since a connected Lie group is diffeomorphic to the product of a Euclidean space times its maximal compact) are exactly the Lie groups of the form $S \rtimes \widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}^k$ where $S$ is a simply connected solvable Lie group and $\widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}$ is the universal cover of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

So the classification reduces to the classification of solvable Lie algebras (then of semidirect products of these Lie algebras with $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})^k$), which I understand to be hopeless.

Comment: To justify the claim: using existence of a Levi factor, a simply connected Lie group has the form $R\rtimes S$ where $R$ is simply connected solvable (hence diffeomorphic to a Euclidean space) and $S$ is semisimple simply connected, and hence a direct product of simple simply connected Lie group. Every simple simply connected Lie group is homotopy equivalent to its maximal compact subgroups, and hence is contractible iff the latter is trivial, which occurs only for the universal covering of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.